# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Compiler_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I just installed Magento but when i try to open the admin panel i get a blank page. The only thing that is visible is the banner. It says

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Compiler_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/app/Mage.php on line 547

Debian 7.8 x64
Nginx
PHP fastcgi

Comment: If you have logging enabled, you should have an error trace, which will give you a clue where the error is caused. I'm guessing your Magento app wasn't installed correctly since that helper should not cause issues.